# How to join two table with the first name in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two table with the following data:

```
              Table A                     Table B
  ID | NAME       | Barcode         Barcode | NAME
  1  | xpto frodo | 0                   201 | xpto frodo
  1  | leto bako  | 0                   369 | roud 
  1  | rodu       | 0                   423 | leto morko
```

I've tried using the following `JOIN` statement but it doesn't seem to work for any row with a . in it.

```
TableA.Name INNER JOIN 
TableB.Name 
ON TableA.Name LIKE '%' + TableB.Name + '%'
```

I get following:

```
              Table A                     Table B
  ID | NAME       | Barcode           Barcode | NAME
  1  | xpto frodo | 201                   201 | xpto frodo
  1  | leto bako  | NULL                  369 | roud 
  1  | rodu       | 369                   423 | leto morko
```

My question is: How can I see a better code that will read the first word in each table to return 423 instead of NULL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the RDBMS you use.

## MySQL

```
TableA.NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING_INDEX(TableB.NAME, ' ', 1), '%')
```

## SQL Server

```
TableA.NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING(TableB.NAME,1,(CHARINDEX(' ',TableB.NAME + ' ')-1)), '%')
```

## PostgreSQL

```
TableA.NAME LIKE '%' || SUBSTR(name,1, POSITION(' ' IN TableB.NAME)) || '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, if you want to join on the part before a space, you can use:

```
TableA a INNER JOIN 
TableB b
ON LEFT(a.name, CHARINDEX(' ', a.name + ' ')) = LEFT(b.name, CHARINDEX(' ', b.name + ' '))
```

This appears to answer your question.  However, you have a major issue with your data model if you are attempting to match on first names and the full names don't even match.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It seems to be working and if there is a problem, I will ask. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any better ideas for my problem with my data model if I try to match on first names and the full names don't even match. Maybe better said if I try to mache the common name from both tables

Comment: @HRS . . . This answers the question that you asked.  I'm simply pointing out that such matching suggests a real problem with your data model, and you might need to consider fixing that.  However, that fix is outside the scope of this question.